# Почему выдает ошибку при несоблюдении условия?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Пишу бота для дискорда, нужно выполнить действие после условия. При этом если условие верно, то ошибки не происходит, но если оно не верно, происходит ошибка. Хотя должна перейти дальше к else:

```
if message.attachments[0,1].filename.endswith('.jpeg') or 
    message.attachments[0,1].filename.endswith('.jpg') or 
    message.attachments[0,1].filename.endswith('.png'):
        print('Hehe boy!')
        return
else:
    return
```

Что я делаю не так?
Ошибка которую просили:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\BlitSpectral\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 39, in on_message
    if message.attachments[0].filename.endswith('.jpeg') or 
message.attachments[0].filename.endswith('.jpg') or 
message.attachments[0].filename.endswith('.png'):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: какая именна ошибка?Место кучи `or` можно писать так `endswith((".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"))`

Comment: Ошибку приведите.

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Добавите всю ошибку в вопрос это можно сделать с помощью кнопки [edit]. Что у вас находится в `message.attachments`

Comment: При соблюденном условии, аттач заканчивается на .png, .jpg, .jpeg. То есть изображение. А при несоблюденном - текст без аттача. Может быть в этом дело?

Comment: перед `if` добавьте строку `print(message.attachments)` и скажите что вы едой

Comment: Текст ошибки не соответствует коду в вопросе.

Comment: [] (при несоблюденном условии). Я так понимаю нужно добавить к оператору if строку
elif message,attachments == '[]':
    return
?

Comment: Если список пустой, то обращение к любому элементу приведёт к этой ошибке.

Comment: Это строчку нужно добавить не в конец,  а в самое начало if.

Comment: Но в таком случае ошибка же никуда не исчезнет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит потому что `message.attachments` может быть пустым. Надо сделать дополнительную проверку на то что он не пустой.

место

```
message.attachments[0].filename.endswith('.jpeg') or 
message.attachments[0].filename.endswith('.jpg') or message.attachments[0].filename.endswith('.png'):
```

лучше писать так:

```
message.attachments[0].filename.endswith(('.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png')):
```

писать везде пустой `return` не надо.

в итогу получается такой код:

```
if message.attachments and message.attachments[0].filename.endswith(('.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png')):
    print('Heheeee Boy!)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался. В данном случае нужно было поставить 2 условие. То есть -

```
if message.attachments == []:
    return
elif message.attachments[0].filename.endswith('.jpeg') or 
    message.attachments[0].filename.endswith('.jpg') or 
    message.attachments[0].filename.endswith('.png'):
    print('Heheeee Boy!)')
    return
else:
    return
```

Такой код работает.

Comment: Надеюсь кому-то помог.